# After crop image , it is black

Tags: php, jcrop

After cropping the image, it is black. Please help me, if you can. Why does it save a back image? What kind of problem happened? Perhaps I need some kind of image library? Here is what I have done so far:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['frm'] == 'desktop' ) {
        $file_cnt   = $_POST['file'];
        $file_size  = filesize($file_cnt);
        $upload_dir = ABSPATH;
        $path       = $upload_dir.'wp-content/themes/poster/destop_imag';

        define('DIRECTORY', $path );
        $img        = rand().time().'.jpg';
        $upload_pt  = $path.'/'.$img;

        if(empty($_POST['wl']) && empty($_POST['hl'])) {
            //move_uploaded_file($file_cnt, $upload_pt);
            $content    = file_get_contents($_POST['file']);
            file_put_contents(DIRECTORY.'/'.$img.'', $content);
        } else {

            $targ_w         = $_POST['wl']; $targ_h = $_POST['hl'];
            $jpeg_quality   = 100;
            $path_parts     = pathinfo($img);
            $newfilename    = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/poster/wp-content/themes/poster/destop_imag/'.$img;

            if ($path_parts['extension'] == 'jpg') {
                $img_r  = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                $dst_r  = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

                imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['xl'],$_POST['yl'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['wl'],$_POST['hl']);

                //header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
                imagejpeg($dst_r,$newfilename,$jpeg_quality);
                //echo '<script>window.location.href="'.get_page_link(27).'?crop_stat=1"</script>';
                //exit;
            } elseif ($path_parts['extension'] == 'png') {
                $img_r  = imagecreatefrompng($src);
                $dst_r  = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

                imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['xl'],$_POST['yl'],
                $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['wl'],$_POST['hl']);

                //header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
                imagepng($dst_r,$newfilename);
                echo '<script>window.location.href="'.get_page_link(27).'?crop_stat=1"</script>';
                exit;
            } elseif ($path_parts['extension'] == 'gif') {
                $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($src);
                $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

                imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['xl'],$_POST['yl'],
                $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['wl'],$_POST['hl']);

                //header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
                imagegif($dst_r,$newfilename);
                echo '<script>window.location.href="'.get_page_link(27).'?crop_stat=1"</script>';
                exit;
            } else {
                echo "Source file is not a supported image file type.";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
            aspectRatio: 1,
            onSelect: updateCoords,
            minSize : [329,329]
        });
    });

    function updateCoords(c)
        {
            $('#x').val(c.x);
            $('#y').val(c.y);
            $('#w').val(c.w);
            $('#h').val(c.h);
        };

    function checkCoords()
        {
            if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
            alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
            return false;
        };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the gd library installed on your server:

For CentOS:

```
sudo yum install php-gd
```

For Debian and Ubuntu :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

You should upload your file like this:
    
        
        Upload new image:

Also, don't try to guess the image MIME type from the file ending, rather get its MIME type directly like that:

```
if($_FILES['userfile']['type']=="image/jpeg") $src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploaddir.$filename);
if($_FILES['userfile']['type']=="image/png") $src_image = imagecreatefrompng($uploaddir.$filename);
```

But i think your error comes from wrong paths:

```
file_put_contents(DIRECTORY.'/'.$img.'', $content);
```

saves the file.
but you load it with

```
$img_r  = imagecreatefrompng($src);
```

what is `$src`? its empty as i see it in your code, so your image is null, which results in a black image after copy.

with the form above, you can process the image like that:

```
$goodimage = 0;
$upload_dir = ABSPATH.'wp-content/themes/poster/destop_imag/';
if(is_array($_FILES['userfile'])) {
    $filename = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    $uploadfile = $upload_dir . $filename;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        if($_FILES['userfile']['type']=="image/jpeg" || $_FILES['userfile']['type']=="image/png") {
    if($_FILES['userfile']['type']=="image/jpeg") $src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploaddir.$filename);
    if($_FILES['userfile']['type']=="image/png") $src_image = imagecreatefrompng($uploaddir.$filename);
    $goodimage = 1;
        } else {
            $error = "Wrong file format: ".$_FILES['userfile']['type']."<br>Please upload in .jpg or .png format.";
        }
    }
}

$newheight = 100;
$x = imagesx($src_image);
$y = imagesy($src_image);
$dst_image_content = imagecreatetruecolor($x/($y/$newheight),$newheight);
imagecopyresampled($dst_image_content, $src_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x/($y/$newheight), $newheight, $x, $y);
imagejpeg($dst_image_content, $upload_dir."resized-".$filename,99);
```

the code loads an image submitted by the form above and resizes it to 100px height, saving it afterwards with filename "resized-".$filename